# How can I get the iMac to recognize a wired mouse after disconnecting the bluetooth mouse?

Tags: mac, usb, mouse, bluetooth

So my bluetooth mouse is working fine but my kids forget to turn it off and I'm using too many batteries.  I've decided to switch to a wired mouse but can't get the Mac to recognize it.  It acts as if I have no mouse at all.  This is driving me crazy as I've turned bluetooth off, plugged the mouse into the keyboard and then into the computers USB drive, nothing seems to work.  I've had to use keyboard commands to turn the bluetooth back on just so that I can get control again.  Help!!